# Error 0xc000007b while opening QGIS 3.10 and 3.12 on Windows 8.1

Tags: qgis, dll, windows-8.1

I have a problem with starting the both versions QGIS 3.10.4 and QGIS 3.12.1.

I have Windows 8.1. It can't start working at all. It needs different `.dll` files.

When I download the file it needs, then it needs another one. I when I download all the files, there is 0xc000007b error. I tried all the ways that are in Google to fix that error and the programme can't start working yet.

Comment: Since when does this problem appaer? Did you try a fresh install? Which QGIS-version are you talking about? Did you consider upgrading to Win10?

Comment: Welcome to our forums. May I know which version of QGIS you have downloaded and installed? Also is your version of Windows 32 or 64 Bit.

Comment: I installed QGIS 3.10.4 and QGIS 3.12.1 yesterday. I haven't worked with the programme yet.

Comment: My version of Windows is 64 bit.

Comment: Try installing the latest version that might help.

Comment: Facing same problem with latest version